# Adding elements to div makes it rise

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper div with a header and an inner content div. For some reason when the inner content div is empty, it looks like this:

[image: firstDiv]

Then when I add some elements, the div appears to rise to the corrent position I want it in:

[image: secondDiv]

This is really puzzling for me, if anyone might explain this strange behavior I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here's the css for the wrapper and inner divs:

```
#wrapperDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25vw;
    top: 5%;
    left: 4%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#innerList {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Let me know if there is any other information that would be helpful!

Comment: There is a padding on your text field or button

Comment: Can you create a working demo of your problem?

Comment: Could be multiple things. Would need to see the rest of your CSS and your markup. It may be because your wrapperDiv is inline-block and your innerList is defaulted to block display. I'm guessing the field and button are floated, or maybe they are inline-block also. Maybe flex. So many possibilities, maybe put up a jsfiddle

Comment: The button does have padding, would that make a difference @SamOrozco Orozco

Comment: Can you post your HTML or it will be a wild guess game all day.

Comment: Here's a basic jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ywbyLdcn/

Comment: This question as it's written is poor quality and no enough info to help OP. All we can do is especulation. Share your working example reproducing the issue or this question should be closed as offtopic

Comment: @MarksCode your *basic*  fiddle doesn't reproduce the issue that you are asking.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your patience. I recreated the error here: https://jsfiddle.net/ywbyLdcn/2/ Just remove the contents of the inner div of 'outer4' div

Answer (score 1):

You can set the height of the yellow div to as much as you need:

```
#innerList {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```